# Programmatically upload file on Sharepoint using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I am new to use ReactJS, I need community help to solve my problem statement.

Problem statement :- I want to upload image file in Sharepoint using ReactJS and as response I want back image's Sharepoint URL, so that I can save in data base to display those images in my application pages.
I am developing a web app and this app is running under teams as tab.

Here is one reference link I have tried but I am unable implement successfully.

http://siddharthvaghasia.com/2019/10/16/upload-file-to-sharepoint-library-using-file-control-and-pnp-js-in-spfx-webpart/

After implementing this I am getting following error:-

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFolderByServerRelativeUrl' of undefined
Settings.uploadFileFromControl
src/components/Settings.jsx:656

```
  653 | //var files = this._input.files;
  654 | //var file = files[0];
  655 | //Upload a file to the SharePoint Library`enter code here`
> 656 | sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(this.props.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl)
      | ^  657 | //sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(this.props.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl + "/MyDocs")
  658 | .files.add(file.name, file, true)
  659 | .then((data) =>{
```

View compiled
FileReader.reader.onloadend
src/components/Settings.jsx:603

```
  600 | 
  601 | //console.log('fileVar[i].name ' + reader.fileName);
  602 | 
> 603 | this.uploadFileFromControl(fileVar[i]);
      | ^  604 | 
  605 | logoImages.push({image: reader.result, name: reader.fileName});
  606 | this.setState({eventLogoImageUrl: JSON.stringify(logoImages)});
```

I am not getting this weather this sp.web will work under teams app or not?

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason for this problem should be that pnp js is not imported correctly.

```
npm install sp-pnp-js --save
```

Run this command in your command bar.

Official example:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#adding-files

If you need further help,please share the full code in tsx file.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically you are getting error because your getFolderByServerRelativeUrl is not getting any value or undefined**

**You need to use the function like this and call this function on the button click**

```
private uploadFileFromControl() {
  //Get the file from File DOM
  var files = this._input.files;
  var file = files[0];
  //Upload a file to the SharePoint Library
var url = this.props.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl;
 pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl( url+ "/FormServerTemplates")
    .files.add(file.name, file, true)
    .then((data) => {
      alert("File uploaded sucessfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert("Error is uploading");
    });
}
```

**In the render use this code of html rendering**

```
return (
    <div className={ styles.maincontainer }>
      <input type="file" ref={(elm) => { this._input = elm; }}></input>
      <p>
      <button onClick={() => this.uploadFileFromControl()} >
                     Upload
                    </button>
                    </p>
    </div>
  
  );
```

**Run this command**

npm install sp-pnp-js --save

**Import sp-pnp-js**

import * as pnp from 'sp-pnp-js';